# Can Oracle to SQL CDC be implemented on the same Oracle table to 2 different SQL instances?

Tags: change-data-capture

I want to distribute Oracle data changes to the same table name in 2 different SQL instances, on 2 different SQL servers. Can Oracle to SQL CDC be implemented on the same Oracle table to 2 different SQL servers/instances?  Going 1 step further, are the LSN transactions able to be distributed independently from source Oracle tables to 2 different SQL servers?